# How to dynamically load the different processing instance

Tags: javascript, jsf, processing.js

I am having Processing.xhtml which has

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="JavaScript" src="../js/processing-1.0.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body onload="doIt();">
        <div style="clear:both; float:left;">
            <canvas id="sketch" data-processing-sources="../js/k12-processing.pde"></canvas>
        </div>
        <script type="application/javascript">
            var pI;
            function doIt() {
                if (!pI) {
                    pI = Processing.getInstanceById('sketch');
                }
                #{script}
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The variable 'pI', function name, canvasId are dynamic ones.

Now i want to draw some number of shapes dynamically in different canvas positioned in different place in a page Shape.xhtml. In Shape.xhtml i am referring Processing instance like this

```
    <ui:include src="/Processing.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="script" value="#{script}"/>
    </ui:include>
```

After including Processing.xhtml my Shapes.xhtml will look like this

```
<ui:composition>
    <ui:define>
        <html>
        ...
         <body onload="doIt_1">
             <canvas id="sketch_1">
             <script>...</script>
         </body>
   </html>

    <html>
    ...
     <body onload="doIt_2">
         <canvas id="sketch_2">
         <script>...</script>
     </body>
   </html>   
</uI:define>
```

The onload event in body element is not triggered properly. How to dynamically load all the scripts in a page?

Answer (score 1):

Web Browsers typically only want one html and one body tag in a single page.  If you really want to wait until the page has completely loaded you can use the window.onload.  For example at the top of your page you can do something like:

```
my_funcs = [];
window.onload = function() {
  for (f in my_funcs) {
    f();
   }
}
```

Then after each of your scripts you can do something like:

```
my_funcs.push(loadFunc);
```

That guarantees that each of your load functions will get executed when the page finishes loading.  However, if you don't really care about the page being fully loaded you could just execute the load function at the end of each script.

Comment: You have a little bug there: f() sould be my_funcs[f]();